# Window builder для IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Здравствуйте. Посоветуйте Window Builder для IDEA. Поставил пробник 20и дневный от JFormDesigner, видел как он лихо готовые классы на Эклипсе переделывает, а у меня кнопка переделать активна, но он ничего не видит, что можно переделать, кароче предлагает начать с нуля. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Поковырялся - разобрался. Всем спасибо. На всякий случай если кто столкнется - нужно создавать новую, чистую форму JFormDesigner, а при создании указать класс Main с того пакета в который хочешь влиться, программа предложит объединить.